# The content that i received through mail as a pdf attachment is partial of the actual content sent

Tags: apex, pdf, singleemailmessage

```
 public static String AcceptTnC(String contractInfo2){

    system.debug('contractId2'+contractInfo2);

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachmentPdf = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    String strObjType = String.valueOf(contractInfo2);
    strObjType=strObjType.replaceAll('</span>','');
    strObjType=strObjType.replaceAll('<span[^>]*>','');
    strObjType=strObjType.replaceAll('<br>','\n');
    strObjType=strObjType.replaceAll('<b>','');
    strObjType=strObjType.replaceAll('</b>','');
    strObjType=strObjType.replaceAll('<*>','');
    strObjType=strObjType.replace('&nbsp;',' ');
    system.debug(' strObjType:'+ strObjType);
    //  Blob b=blob.valueOf(strObjType);

    attachmentPdf.setContentType('application/pdf');
    attachmentPdf.setFileName('Partner Program agreement.pdf');
    blob Agree_blob=blob.toPDF(strObjType);
    system.debug('Blob value:'+Agree_blob.toString());
    attachmentPdf.setBody(Agree_blob);
    //system.debug(attachmentPdf);
    /*doc.Name='Partner Program agreement';
    doc.ContentType='text/plain';
    doc.body=blob.valueOf(strObjType);
    doc.Type = 'doc';
    system.debug('doc id'+doc.id);
    insert doc;*/

    //  semail.setEntityAttachments(doc);*/
    semail.setPlainTextBody('hi this is pdf type email at 13th may');
    semail.setSubject('Partner Program agreement');
    String[] sendTo = new String[]{'xyz@gmail.com'};
    semail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
    system.debug('address set'+sendTo);


    semail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attachmentPdf});
    system.debug('reached to set File attachments..');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{semail});  
    system.debug('mail sent to '+sendTo);
    return null;


}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to go through [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/262281/edit) to provide necessary details including any errors that you may be receiving. In its current form the question lacks the details for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: it is not clear for me what is your issue....

Comment: I am using apex to send email with pdf attachment, but the content in the pdf file is getting trimmed. the actual data (i.e data in ContractInfo2 ) is of size 21.1 KB but I am receiving only 2.1 KB of file in email.

Comment: You can't compare byte sizes when you're running a number of `replaceAll()` regexes on the content before sending. The result should not be expected to be the same size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but the thing is actual content is also getting trimmed. becoz i have first replaced all the html tags and then through strObjType i am converting it into pdf,hence data from strObjType should not get trimmed and should be sent as it is,which is not happening in my case.

Comment: @David Reed,@Vijay Ganji,@m Peixoto